# Rails: How Do I Link Images to Render a Partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code to use images as links to pages on the website. I would like to link images to partials as well.

```
  <%= link_to root_path do %>
     <%= image_tag "card-icon.jpg" %>
  <% end %>
```

How do I replace the root_path portion to render a partial? (Pretend my partial is _window.html.erb). Or is there another way to render partials through images?

Comment: You don't link to partials. Partials are rendered within a html.erb page so link to a path that renders some_windows.html.erb and in that some_windows.html.erb render the partial. Or use javascript to load the partial into the section of the page you are currently on. If this is what you want to do then look up `http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised` it is very old but itl'll give you a starting point